Blender gives a `NameError` error when calling get_strokes()
I'm currently working on an addon for Blender that turns the camera view into an SVG. There's this error that shows up when I try calling get_strokes()
File "d:\Blender builds\Blender 4.2.1\4.2\scripts\freestyle\modules\freestyle\utils.py", line 95, in get_strokes
    return tuple(map(Operators().get_stroke_from_index, range(Operators().get_strokes_size())))
 
NameError: name 'Operators' is not defined

This function exists in Blender's api.
It's the first time I'm coding an addon for Blender, so I might be missing something obvious.
To replicate this, you can run the following code inside Blender:
import bpy
from freestyle.utils import get_strokes

var = get_strokes()

I really need to get the strokes from the freestyle linesets for the project I'm working on at work. I'm now stuck on this part. I tried looking into the code of the existing addon Freestyle SVG Exporter to try to find how to do it, but I'm very lost.
